# Check if any activity is resumed for background service?

Tags: android

I've seen similar questions asked where they wanted to know if they could find if a specific activity was running from a service. This is not what I want to do. I want to be able to tell if the user is currently using any activity on my app.

My use case is that I have a monitoring `Service` that monitors many session-related things, such as a `Socket` connection. If the `Socket` connection fails at any point, the monitoring `Service` is made aware and will have to let the user know. However, I only want to let the user know if he is using my app. If he pressed on the home button to check something elsewhere, I don't want to let him know. If he is using my app, I show him a dialog.

My issue is that I need to be able to check if there is any `Activity` currently resumed. If so, then I show a dialog to my user.

I've seen many solutions that are in my opinion pretty bad. I don't want to hold a `boolean` that is constantly updated by activities to know if an activity is running. I want to be able to cleanly tell if there is a resumed activity and show a dialog if that's the case. Remember that I am in a `Service`, so I don't have a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) in the AndroidX Lifecycle library and check if the current lifecycle state is at least `STARTED` (visible to the user) or `RESUMED` (frontmost), depending on your preference.  Its lifecycle is the composite of all `Activity` lifecycles in your app, so this will check if any `Activity` is in that state.

Also:

> Remember that I am in a `Service` so I don't have a context.

`Service` extends `Context`, so you can use use the `Service` as a `Context` like you would with an `Activity`.

Comment: Wow, this works great! By far the best solution for this problem.